# Reverse an XML sitemap

Tags: xml, sitemap

Working with a client and a massive website. He sends me the XML sitemap, but its full of blog posts, categories, and pages. I can technically navigate it, but its a bear at 10k lines long.

Is there a tool or way to simple get all the page URLs out in a nice list? maybe using UL / LI to identify parent/child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of XSL Stylesheets for XML Sitemaps. Just google for it. However, here is a nice one http://yoast.com/xsl-stylesheet-xml-sitemap/